# how to define defaultprops using hook useIntl

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

Recently I started using the hook `useIntl`, previously I was using the HOC `injectIntl`. Now I am facing a problem I can't find a solution, how to internationalize the defaultProps?

Something like:

```
function Component(props) {
    const intl = useIntl();
    const {name} = props;

    return (
      <div>
         {intl.formatMessage({id: 'welcome'}, {user: name})}
      <div/>
    );
}

Component.defaultProps = {
   name: 'unknown'; <<---------- how to replace this plain string with intl...?
}

Component.propTypes = {
   name: PropType.string
}

export default Component;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FormattedMessage`:

```js
import { FormattedMessage, useIntl } from 'react-intl';

function Component(props) {
    const intl = useIntl();
    const {name} = props;

    return (
      <div>
         {intl.formatMessage({id: 'welcome'}, {user: name})}
      <div/>
    );
}

Component.defaultProps = {
   name: <FormattedMessage id="unknownKey" />
}

Component.propTypes = {
   name: PropType.string
}

export default Component;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to do this, here is the solution I found:

```
function Component(props) {
    const intl = useIntl();
    let {name} = props;

    if (!name) {
      name = intl.formatMessage({id: 'unknownKey'});
    }

    return (
      <div>
         {intl.formatMessage({id: 'welcome'}, {user: name})}
      <div/>
    );
}

Component.defaultProps = {
   name: null
}

Component.propTypes = {
   name: PropType.string
}

export default Component;
```